# Angularjs get variable in the view

Tags: angularjs, controller

Im trying to catch the variables fromcontroller  to use it in the view. but it wont work, but i do know that it exists ( debug on the picture below).

problem: I dont get anything in the view.

note: it might be cause the structure, 
main structure is from: https://github.com/meanjs/mean

response:

```
nothing
```

my view:

```
<body class="ng-cloak" ng-controller="HeaderController as aux">
```

trying to get it to work:

```
        <div class="cometchat_name">{{ varselmessage }} {{ aux.varselmessage }}</div>
```

function:

```
    (function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('core')
    .controller('HeaderController', HeaderController);

  HeaderController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'Authentication', '$rootScope','Socket'];

  function HeaderController($scope, $state, Authentication, $rootScope,Socket) {

    var aux = this;

    $scope.datatest = 200001;
    $rootScope.datatest = 900;

    $scope.varselmessage = 'varsel';
    aux.varselmessage = 'varsel2';

    $scope.notifications = [{text: " melding" , image : "kapring"}];
    console.log("loaded , maybe possible4?");

  }
}());
```

[image]

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: hmm try to paste more code, are you using `routing`?

Comment: Yea, but I want this controller to run on body. I linked to the structure I'm using

Comment: with the code provided can only guess, try to remove the `controller as` syntax

Comment: no difference @Akis

Comment: Is your  ´console.log("loaded , maybe possible4?");´
 showing on the console ?

Comment: Yes ITS showing

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the module, you are missing the  dependency injection part `[]`,

```
  angular
    .module('core',[])
    .controller('HeaderController', HeaderController);
```

[`DEMO APP`](https://plnkr.co/edit/MtYL1lqNpeHNlVC2uiVQ?p=preview)

Comment: i think something in my structure is blocking it. Could you take a look? ( in 2 days im setting a 100 bounty on this too)

Comment: @maria actually i dont get your issue! your issue is the values are not showing in the view right?

Comment: so that is what fixed with the demo application, can you have a look?

Comment: yeah i see it works in the demo. But i did the same thing, and it wont work for some reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123274/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-maria).